# Cutting and reorganizing numbers in a file with C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dataframe, stream

I have the following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstdio>



int main() {

//Here the code that creates the file benchmarks_cleaned.dat

int ncol = 16; //number of data per row
double datos[ncol];
char aux2;
double aux3;
int icol;

ifstream benchmarks2;
ofstream out_benchmarks2;

benchmarks2.open("benchmarks_cleaned.dat");
out_benchmarks2.open("benchmarks_final.dat");

if (benchmarks2.is_open()) {//second if

  for (icol = 0; icol < ncol; icol++) {
    benchmarks2>>datos[icol];
    out_benchmarks2<<datos[icol]<<" ";
  };

  out_benchmarks2<<"\n";
  benchmarks2.get(aux2);

  while (aux2 != 'X') {
    benchmarks2.unget();
    benchmarks2>>aux3;

    if (aux3 != datos[0]) {
      benchmarks2.get(aux2);
    } else {
      out_benchmarks2<<datos[0]<<" ";
      for (icol = 1; icol < ncol; icol++) {
        benchmarks2>>datos[icol];
        out_benchmarks2<<datos[icol]<<" ";
      };

      out_benchmarks2<<"\n";
      benchmarks2.get(aux2);

    };

  };

} else {
  cout<<"ERROR: unable to open the file"<<endl;
};//end of second if

out_benchmarks2<<"X";

out_benchmarks2.close();

out_benchmarks2.close();
benchmarks2.close();


return 0;
}; //end of main
```

The data file dummyValues.dat is:

```
{5.12, 0.1, 0.25}   {{0.10, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1.44, 10.2}}       {11.1, 12.2, 13.3, 14.4, 15.5, 16.6} 1000 2000 {{{{ 5.12, 0.1} {17.7, 18.08, 19.0, 020.0}   {1.115, 2.0, 3.01, 4.65, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.0}, 3000 4000    { 5.12, 0.1} {117.7, 118.08, 119.0, 0120.0}   {11.115, 21.0, 31.01, 41.65, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 110.0} 5000 6000       X
```

In benchmarks_cleaned.dat you reduce this file to just numbers separated by a blank space. The idea now is to write benchmarks_final.dat where in each row you have only 16 values and they must start by the same number `5.12 = datos[0]` that you can check is repeated along dummyValues.dat

Nonetheless, while benchmarks_cleaned.dat is indeed created as desired (see below), benchmarks_final.dat does never start. I've checked that the programme runs but it does not write anything in benchmarks_final.dat. Where is the mistake?

benchmarks_cleaned.dat is:

```
5.12 0.1 0.25 0.1 4 3 2 1 1.44 10.2 11.1 12.2 13.3 14.4 15.5 16.6 1000 2000 5.12 0.1 17.7 18.08 19 20 1.115 2 3.01 4.65 5 6 7 8 9 10 3000 4000 5.12 0.1 117.7 118.08 119 120 11.115 21 31.01 41.65 51 61 71 81 91 110 5000 6000 X
```

Comment: If `benchmarks_cleaned.dat` has been written correctly, and the purpose of this code is to rea it and write `benchmarks_final.dat`, then please give us `benchmarks_cleaned.dat`, along wit henough code to reproduce the problem. (See the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: @Beta I have edited the post including ```benchmarks_cleaned.dat```. With that data file and the code already given to create ```benchmarks_final.dat``` I think is enough. Let me know if you think otherwise

Comment: @Vicky You might have quite a bit *more* code than you need for a [mre]. The problem is that nothing is ever written to `benchmarks_final.dat`, right? Why don't you get rid of the big `if-else` statement, leaving just opening the file, writing `"X"` and closing the file? Much simpler code if that still fails to write to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calls to `get(...)` are catching blank spaces and missing the 'X'.

There's no need for `get`. Get rid of `aux2` and change the `while` loop to:

```
while(benchmarks2 >> aux3)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is given. It is good, correct. It is upvoted and accepted. Very good.

Just as an additional information, I will show a C++ solution, using more modern language elements. This solution skips the intermediate file (Can be generated by an one-liner) and also has no need to use the 'X' (Could also be added very simply).

With using the STL, we can come up with a solution, from the original source file to the final destination file in net 5 lines of code.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::regex reFloat{ R"([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)" };

using SVector = std::vector<std::string>;
using SVectorIter = SVector::iterator;

int main() {
    // Open source file and check, if it coud be opened
    if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream{ "r:\\dummyValues.dat" }; sourceFileStream) {

        // Open destination file and check, if it could be opened
        if (std::ofstream finalFileStream("r:\\benchmarks_final.dat"); finalFileStream) {

            // Algorithm start ----------------------------------------------------------
            // Define a string variable and initialize it with the contents of the file
            std::string completeFile(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFileStream), {});

            // Define vector and initialize it with all float values from the file
            SVector values(std::sregex_token_iterator(completeFile.begin(), completeFile.end(), reFloat), {});

            // Iterate over the vector and find the next value equal to first-value
            for (SVectorIter svi{ values.begin() }; (svi = std::find(svi, values.end(), values[0])) != values.end(); ++svi) {

                 // Copy 16 value to the final file
                std::copy_n(svi, std::min(16, std::distance(svi, values.end())), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(finalFileStream, " "));
                finalFileStream << '\n';
            }
            // Algorithm end ----------------------------------------------------------
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open final file\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n";
    }
}
```

I guess not, but if you should have interest in understanding that, then I will explain to you. Please ask, I am happy to help.

---

**EDIT** You are interested in further explanations. That is OK, but I can of course not give a whole tutorial here.

Then let us start with some important feature that we are using here. The so called `constructor`. This you should know already. It is a special function of a class and basically used to "initialize" the data of a class. If you have a class like

```
struct MyClass {
    int a;
    // Constructor. Very simplified
    MyClass(int value) { a = value; }
};
```

And if you want to define a variable of this type (create an instance of this type), the you can write:

```
MyClass test(3);
```

This will call the constructor and assign 3 to the class member `a`. You should basically know this already. If you look for classes in the [C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/), then you will always find a constructor for the defined classes.

Ok, then let's start now. First, we want to open a file for input. For this, we will use the STL class `std::ifstream`. And we will use one of it's [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream). Please look at the reference. The constructor 2 takes a filename as a `const char*` and opens the file. It implicitely calls open (see description in the link). The destructor, which will be called automatically, when the variable falls out of scope (After the next matching `}`. The destructor will automatically close the file for you. That is very good, and avoids mistakes.

So, you can write:

```
    // Some previous code here
    // . . .

    {   
        // Some previous code here
        // . . .

        // Open the file
        std::ifstream sourceFileStream{ "r:\\dummyValues.dat" };

        // more code
        // . . .

    }  // Now the scope is closed. The Variable "sourceFileStream" will fall out of scope
       //  and the file will be close automatically.
```

Cool.

Now a very important recommendation. You should always check, if an IO operation was successful. How to do that. For that, you should know, that `std::stream` have a kind of error state. And you can and should check this. You can read about those "states" [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). If, you open a file, and it does not work. the the `failbit` will be set. This you can read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open). So, you can check the failbit with the statement:

```
if (sourceFileStream.rdstate() == std::ios_base::failbit)
```

But that is somehow complicated. So, the designers of the IO-stream classes have defined a [bool operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) for the class. And, as you can read in the description, it checks whether the stream has no errors. An `if` statement needs a boolean condition. And if you write

```
    if (sourceFileStream) {
```

then the boolean operator of this variable is returned and shows, if there is an error or not. That is very helpful.

Next, in C++17, a new syntax for the [if statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) has been introduced. Now you can define and initialize a variable within the if statement. For example

```
    if (int inner = 0; x < y) {  . . . }
```

Still the condition is `x < y`. Additionally, the variable "inner" will be defined and the advantage is that this variable is only visible in the inner scope of the `if` statement. After the closing bracket `}` of the if block, the variable will be gone.

And now, we can put all peices together:

```
    if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream{ "r:\\dummyValues.dat" }; sourceFileStream) {
```

The first part of this `if` statement defines a variable "sourceFileStream" and calls its constructor with the filename. And so, it opens the file. The second part of the `if statement` is the condition, and calls the bool operator of the "sourceFileStream", to check, if the file could be opened. And the good thing is, the the variable "sourceFileStream", is only vidible within the `if` block. There is no need to have it available outside of this block, because, if the file could not be opened, then what would you do with it. And, additionally. After the `if` block is finished with "}", then the file will be automatically closed, because the variable falls out of scope, which will call the destructor.

Wow, that was a big explanation for one line of code.

---

Next line:

```
std::string completeFile(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFileStream), {});
```

Uh, oh. What is that?

Obviously, we define a variable with the name "completeFile" with the data type `std::string`. Ok, that is still understandable. And then we have a (...), so calling the `std::string`s constructor. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) about the constructor number 6. It says:

> Constructs the string with the contents of the range [first, last).

So, it takes a `iterator` to the first item of the range and an iterator to after the last item of the range. And then, it copies all characters in this range to the variable "completeFile". So it will fill out `std::string` with characters given by the 2 iterators.

So, nect part: `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFileStream)`. This is the `begin` iterator of the range. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator), that

> std::istreambuf_iterator is a single-pass input iterator that reads successive characters from the std::basic_streambuf object for which it was constructed.

So, this thing reads successive characters from our "sourceFileStream". It will read character aftr character from the source file and copies them in our string variable. It does this until the `end` iterator, so until `{}`. Hm, whats that? This is the empty braced default initializer and it will simply call the default constructor. And if you look into the description of the `std::istreambuf_iterator`s [constructor number 1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/istreambuf_iterator), then you see that it will be the "end-of-stream iterator". And, with that, all characters from thesource file, from the firts character to the last character, will be read and copied into our `std::string` variable "completeFile".

Cool, right? Defining a avriable and reading the complete source file at the same time.

---

Next line:

```
std::vector<std::string>  values(std::sregex_token_iterator(completeFile.begin(), completeFile.end(), reFloat), {});
```

This is maybe too complicated for here and I can therefore only explain the basics. So, first, we will define a varaible with the name "values" of the type `````` std::vector`````of ``````std::strings`. So, we want to store many`std::strings`in a`std::vector````. That is understandable. And guess what, we will initialize this variable by using its constructor. And we will use again the range constructor, here [constructor number 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). And this

> Constructs the container with the contents of the range [first, last).

So basically the same as with the `std::string` above. It copies all strings, pointed to by the iterators, from first to last, into our vector. The `begin` iterator is the [std::sregex_token_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator). I cannot explain the `regex` theory here, but simply said, it will iterate over a pattern of similar items, defined by a regex in a "meta-language" and return them, so that they can be copyied into our vector.

And the pattern is that of a float value. If you look at a float value, then you can detect a pattern. It consists of optional +- signs, then some digits, maybe a period and more digits. That is always the same. And this pattern, we describe with the regex `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`. You can copy and paste that into [here](https://regex101.com/) and play with it. Then you may get a first understanding.

Back to the iterator. So, it will only return strings, that match with the patterns. So, it will only return float-value-strings. It will not return any other characters. Just those, that you need.

And similar as above, it starts with the first pattern in the given string and stops at {}. Same as above, the [default constructor no 1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator) "Constructs the end-of-sequence iterator."

---

If you are interested in more, please comment, and I will explain the rest

Comment: Is this working without taking into account tabs? Amin, does it work even if there are tabs in dummyValues.dat? (In my original file I didn't use tabs but succesive blank spaces and I'm having now problems to obtain benchmarks_final.dat if dummyValues.dat goes with tabs among the data)

Comment: Tabs are not a problem.

Comment: I would like some more information about how your code get rid of  ```{ } ,``` symbols, the blanck spaces and the tabs, so your final file is just numbers separated by one blanck space. All the commands you apply are far from my knowledge. Thank you

Comment: I tried to use your code but I got a big error that says (naming your code finalCode.cpp):                    ```finalCode.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
finalCode.cpp:16:9: warning: init-statement in selection statements only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
     if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream{ "r:\\dummyValues.dat" }; sourceFileStream) {
         ^~~ ```
 and goes on...

Comment: This software uses C++17 features. As the error message says, you need to tell your compiler to use this. Wit flage -c++17 or with -c++1z.. I will edit my answer and give further explanations